# Spring boot: PATCH doesn't map model while identical POST method does

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot

I have the following two REST-methods:

```
@PostMapping
public Object create(@ModelAttribute("building") @Validated Building building) {
    if (building != null && !(building.getName().equals("") || building.getAddress().equals(""))) {
        return buildingDao.save(building);
    }
    return HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND;
}

@PatchMapping
public Object update(@ModelAttribute("building") @Validated Building building) {
    if (building.getId() != null && buildingDao.findById(building.getId()).isPresent()) {
        return buildingDao.save(building);
    }
    return HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND;
}
```

As you can see they are exact, except one method is POST while the other one is PATCH.

My problem is that 'building' won't map when I use the PATCH method. I have tried to remove @Validated, and all the fields are null. Testing has been done with Postman and axios (javascript). I don't quite understand why it won't work then the POST method works flawlessly.

I'm using Spring Boot 2.0.0.RELEASE

Maybe relevant code:
Controller definition:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/buildings")
public class BuildingController { [...] }
```

I can gladly add more code if that is necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by changing @ModelAttribute to @RequestBody.